# how to install guest additions virtual box in 13.04

Tags: virtualbox

When i tried installing guest additions im getting  the below error

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additons-iso
[sudo] password for gan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-guest-additons-iso
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm thinking you've spelled it wrong.

```
apt-cache search virtualbox-guest-additions
virtualbox-guest-additions-iso - guest additions iso image for VirtualBox
```

You're missing the "i" in "tions".